# Asterisk причины сбоев и помех

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip

Случай 1, звоним с внешнего номера на внутренний, принимает GSM-гейт.
Качество связи отличное
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Случай 2, звоним со внутреннего, на внешний, через GSM-гейт но другой.
Слышимость хорошая, помех нет, но есть прервыания, как будто собеседник (звонящий) пускает пузыри воздуха из под воды, он при этом внешнего может слышать приемлимо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Звонок с внутреннего на внутренний сопровождается отличной слышимостью собеседника.

Вопрос, какие у вас могут быть догадки по этому поводу, различные теории и домыслы, приму к сведению все, потому как я просто не знаю, с чего начать разбираться.

CentOS 6.5
Asterisk 11.2
шлюзы - Huawei e171, 2 входящих  ,2 исходящих, оператор Megafon. Расположены рядом друг с другом. Если сим-карты вставить в моб.телефоны проблем со связью нет.

Answer (score 1):

Прошивки одинаковые на GSM шлюзах?

Предлагаю:

```
1) проверить уровень сигнала на проблемном шлюзе;
2) попробовать разнести шлюзы подальше друг от друга, подключить в разные порты.
```

Comment: Попробую, а насчет разноса, они могут как-то глушить друг друга?